# Django 1.6 You cannot add messages without installing django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware

Tags: python, django

I am totally new to Django and using Django 1.6 , 
I have User Registration form I am using Django `Messaging` module.

But when I submit form I get an error :

`You cannot add messages without installing django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware`

I have `django.contrib.messages` in INSTALLED_APPS and `django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware` in MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES.

I have looked at solution provided in this [**Thread**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15852317/you-cannot-add-messages-without-installing-django-contrib-messages-middleware-me?answertab=votes#tab-top) but it didn't worked for me.

Here is the code:

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'south',
    'usersapp',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
)
```

**Views.py:**

```
class RegisterView(FormView):
    template_name = 'register_form.html'
    form_class = RegisterForm

    def form_valid(self, request):
        f = RegisterForm(self.request.POST)
        f.save()

        messages.info(request, "User added.")
        return redirect('/usersapp')
```

If anyone having this problem and have solution. Please post.

Comment: Make sure you have restarted the server after updating your settings file.

Comment: @Alasdair I have restarted server but still it is not working.

Comment: Try deleting settings.pyc

Comment: have you ever fixed this? I'm having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same problem, and this is what solution I found:
I had a decorator for a method on a CBV; this decorator would check the permissions and issue a message and redirect if the were not valid. The way to resolve was to use the method_decorator decorator to call the decorator function, so:

```
class MyView(FormView):
...
@custom_permission_required('my.permission')
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
```

became:

```
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
...
class MyView(FormView):
...
@method_decorator(custom_permission_required('my.permission'))
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
```