# Unit testing an authenticated user in Django

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-testing

I am trying to test access as a logged in user. I'm having trouble with the `Client()`.

```
def test_taking_too_much_time(self):
    my_client = Client()
    my_client.login(username='exampleuser', password='testing12345')
    response = my_client.get('/example/link/')
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

> Okay could you also provide the whole stacktrace?

I see, that friend has a similar problem. [Django - Testing Login View - AttributeError: 'HttpRequest' object has no attribute 'user'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69057055/django-testing-login-view-attributeerror-httprequest-object-has-no-attrib)
After adding the 'user' instance in the argument and replacing with request.

```
@receiver (user_logged_in, sender = Person)
def when_logging_in (request, sender, user, ** kwargs):
     messages.info (request, f '{user.username} hello.')
```

The trouble persists and the same thing appears, which is `AttributeError: 'HttpRequest' object has no attribute 'user'`. The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70451317) below is an expansion of the topic.

Comment: Can you provide the code of the login view and the view where the error is thrown?

Comment: Okay could you also provide the whole stacktrace? ^^

Comment: I added an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the `Client()`, rather we are using the `RequestFactory` and passing the resulting`request` object to the views directly.

```
def test_taking_too_much_time(self):
    factory = RequestFactory()
    request= factory.get('/example/link/',)
    request.user = self.user
    response = ExampleLinkView.as_view()(request)
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

The login is bypassed, because no middlewares will be applied.
You can read more about that here [Advanced Testing](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/testing/advanced/).

Comment: I also use 'RequestFactory ()' in a lot of tests. There I also add different types of users, their permissions and check their behavior. I create different users, also anonymous ones, but I wanted to run a 'Client' test taking into account the entire authentication backend. 'RequestFactory' didn't cause me so much trouble even in advanced tests where 'Client' hangs on authorization.

Answer (score 0):

I spent more time on it and checked all the signal code, related functions, dependencies, project settings. There is a lot of it. The culprit is the `Client()` which serves the backend but has trouble with the `HttpRequest`.

```
@receiver (user_logged_in, sender = Person)
def when_logging_in (request, sender, user, ** kwargs):
      messages.info (request, f '{user.username} hello.')
```

It's okay to use an `instance` instead of a `request`, but not for `messages` where one of the arguments is `request`. So, where could a `message` to the user be placed so as not to lose functionality, but to perform unit tests using `Client()`.