# Django mock message fails with module view

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, mocking, django-views

I am trying to make a test pass with a mocked function:

```
@mock.patch('apps.myapp.views.messages')
def test_message_get_called(self, messages):
    # tests
    assert messages.add_message.called
```

This tests pass perfectly by default, no problem here.
Because I have a long `views.py` file I try to refactor. Instead of having a single file, I create a folder named `views`, put my `views.py` inside as `all.py` and add the following `__init__.py`:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import   
from .all import ( 
    ....
    )
```

So I import all my views class into this file to have access to them. This make the application work without problem, so I'm guessing the tests should be fine.

But it turns out the test fails:

```
AttributeError: <module 'apps.myapp.views' from '.../views/__init__.pyc'> 
does not have the attribute 'messages'
```

So I add `messages` in my list of import. And I get the following error:

```
MessageFailure: You cannot add messages without installing
django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware
```

I already found that using middleware during test may cause problem:

- https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/17971
- [Why don't my Django unittests know that MessageMiddleware is installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11938164)

But my tests seems to pass without the module, and it fails with.

What can be the issue here ?