# Django 1.9 unittest error for messages but i dont see the error for 1.10.4 and 1.8

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-1.9

The test fails with the error in Django 1.9 env, **but tests run perfectly well in 1.10.4 and 1.8. Can someone throw some light here !**

Here is the error

> add_message
>       raise MessageFailure('You cannot add messages without installing '
>   MessageFailure: You cannot add messages without installing django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware

Check https://travis-ci.org/invaana/Hydronium/builds/182190626 for complete errors

**views.py**

```
def contact(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Operation Successful! This is demo. Im not sending any messages')
        else:
            form.errors
            messages.error(request, 'Message not sent, Please fix the errors!.' )
    else:
        form = ContactForm()
    return render(request, 'pages/contact.html', {'form': form})
```

**tests.py**

```
def test_contactform_valid(self):
    res = self.client.post(reverse('contact'), {'name':'Ravi','email':'rrmerugu@gmail.com', 'text': 'im good' })
    self.assertIn('Operation Successful', res.content)

def test_contactform_invalid(self):
    res = self.client.post(reverse('contact'), {'name':'Ravi','email':'rrmerugu@gmail.com', 'text': '' })
    self.assertIn('Message not sent', res.content)
```

Comment: Look into this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11938164/why-dont-my-django-unittests-know-that-messagemiddleware-is-installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently,

> MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES is used in 1.9, 1.8
>
> MIDDLEWARE is used in 1.10.4.

To make the middleware compatible for both, I used the following code in `settings.py`

```
MIDDLEWARE = MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```