# Django message error

Tags: python, django, exception, middleware, message

The following error is being thrown by my Django code on my VPS when I try to use messages:

You cannot add messages without installing django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware

Exception Type: MessageFailure
Exception Value:
You cannot add messages without installing django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware

I do have all the appropriate settings in my settings.py file. My VPS is running Django 1.9.6. The same error is not thrown when I run the code locally on my laptop. On my laptop, I have Django 1.10.3 running. Are there any differences in the treatment of messages between Django 1.9.6 and 1.10.3 that would cause this to happen? It seems that on Django 1.9.6 my settings in settings.py are being ignored.

Relevant code in settings.py is as follows:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
```

]

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
```

]

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: can you post your settings.py file

Comment: it looks like messages app is not in you settings file

Comment: `django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages` check this in your context processors

Comment: Please review the code in my post.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

follow the code with the order of each

Comment: I tried your order and it didn't make a difference.

Comment: Any other suggestions? It's not the order of the settings or the settings themselves, but rather that the settings are not taking affect on the VPS.

Comment: Are there any alternatives to using messages in Django?

Comment: Is it related to this article? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11938164/why-dont-my-django-unittests-know-that-messagemiddleware-is-installed. I ask because this bug was specific to Django 1.4 but I'm not sure if it was fixed until 1.10.